# After using the command ionic cap add android i changed my code in vscode but now there is no change in the apk i download from android stdudio

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, ionic-framework, ionic4

after running the command from terminal i opened the android studio from where i generated the apk
now i made some changes in the vs code which were reflected in the browser by using the ionic server
but now after making the changes in the code in vscode if i download the apk from android studio again it is not reflecting the changes

i have tried closing android studio and again using the command
ionic cap add android

Comment: Depending on which CLI version are you using, you need to build and then copy to the platforms, something like `ionic build` and then `npx cap copy android`, or `ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 2):

You need to sync your changes in your IDE/project with Android Studio. Run the following commands:

```
 ionic build
 npx cap sync
 npx cap copy
 npx cap open android
```

Comment: i actually solved it by deleting the android and the ios files and then using the command 
ionic cap add android and ionic cap add ios again but i will try this too thanks .